# Laravel with Ajax request getting 401 Unauthorized on mobile only sometimes

Tags: ajax, laravel, http-status-code-401

I'm working on a web application with Laravel 5.6 which uses [bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) and some forms with file uploads. All the requests are made with Ajax and I have no problem using it from my desktop browser (Chrome on Windows). The only problem appears when I use it from mobile (Chrome on Android or Samsung Internet etc.). Sometimes I got the **401 unauthenticated** error message in the response. This error appears absolutely random: 1 or 2 GET/POST requests working with success, another 1-2 requests getting unauthenticated error...

I have made some ajax setup like this, but the error persists:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
});
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you sending ajax requests back-to-back in quick succession?

Comment: I have also made some tests sending requests once 2-3 seconds. Most cases it works very well, but sometimes not. It's a little bit annoying...

Answer (score 0):

Check by using the following code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

When making simultaneous XHR requests, session data may be lost due to concurrent requests updating the session at the same time. This is a known issue. One solution may be reducing the number of requests, or use **session locking **. This allows to lock the session file when used, hence forcing all requests to be executed one after the other. This may slow down your app, but eliminate the potential errors.

Laravel does not include session locking by default. Someone made a Laravel package to add the feature. https://github.com/rairlie/laravel-locking-session

Comment: Hi & thank you for the answer. Apparently this locking-session feature reduces the number of errors, but the problem is still persistent. I've done some tests with concurrent requests and in 80% from cases it works. What about the rest? :)